# Can't connect to RabbitMQ on Window Server 2012?

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-server-2012

I've installed RabbitMQ 3.5.5 on Windows Server 2012 as a service by first installing Erlang (32 bit) and then following the RabbitMQ manual install instructions (https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html)

The Windows service starts up fine, but nothing can connect.

When I run `rabbitmq_server-3.5.5\sbin\rabbitmqctl.bat status` I get the following output:

> rabbit@XXXXXXXX:
>
> - connected to epmd (port 4369) on XXXXXXXX
> - epmd reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672
> - TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
> - suggestion: hostname mismatch?
> - suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?
> - suggestion: is the Erlang distribution using TLS?
>
> current node details:
>
> - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-1444@XXXXXXXX'
> - home dir: C:\Users\userxxxx
> - cookie hash: XDarCC/CmuhQpUEo95dj8g==

From the output and from `netstat` I can see that rabbit is running on port 4369.

I can start the server manually using `rabbitmq-server.bat` and everything works.

I can't find any additional cookies floating around except for the one in my user directory (`C:\Users\userxxxx`).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have .erlang.cookie inside `c:\windows` . Have you copied the file as described here? https://www.rabbitmq.com/windows-quirks.html `Copy the file .erlang.cookie manually from %SystemRoot% to %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%. `

Comment: Arrggh, you are right, thanks. That fix it.

Comment: you are welcome, I report the comment for future reader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a typo.

Are you sure that you don't have `.erlang.cookie` inside `c:\windows` . Have you copied the file as described [here](http://rabbitmq.com/windows-quirks.html)?

> Copy the file .erlang.cookie manually from %SystemRoot% to
>   %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%.