# RabbitMQ Can't join Cluster and enable Plugin

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I try to setting cluster for my RabbitMQ , but when join cluster it error i don't know why, spent one day to find solution but still no hope.
( I'm using Window and install with all default option).

**Promblem 1:**
**Can't join Cluster:**
I have 2 computer install Rabbit:

- rabbit@HOANGQUOCVI2118
- ALO-PC

I able to telnet port of ALO-PC , turn off firewall too, but can't join Cluster by this command:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ
>   Server\rabbitmq_server-3.5.6\sbin>rabbitmqctl join_cluster
>   rabbit@ALO-PC Clustering node rabbit@HOANGQUOCVI2118 with
>   'rabbit@ALO-PC' ...
>
> Error: unable to connect to nodes
>   ['rabbit@ALO-PC']: nodedown
>
> ## DIAGNOSTICS
>
> attempted to contact: ['rabbit@ALO-PC']
>
> rabbit@ALO-PC:   * connected to epmd (port 4369) on ALO-PC   * epmd
>   reports node 'rabbit' running on port 25672   * TCP connection
>   succeeded but Erlang distribution failed   * suggestion: hostname
>   mismatch?   * suggestion: is the cookie set correctly?   * suggestion:
>   is the Erlang distribution using TLS?
>
> current node details:
>   - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-248@HOANGQUOCVI2118'
>   - home dir: C:\Users\quocviet
>   - cookie hash: 0B/cSw97VtsfE3zp8Y+Jbg==

**Promblem 2:**
**Can't enable plugin:**

**Federation:**

> c:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ
>   Server\rabbitmq_server-3.5.6\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable
>   rabbitmq_federation
>
> The following plugins have been enabled:
>   rabbitmq_federation
>
> Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@HOANGQUOCVI2118... failed.
>   Error: {noproc,
>              {gen_server,call,
>                  [rabbit_sup,
>                   {start_child,
>                       {rabbit_federation_sup,
>                           {rabbit_federation_sup,start_link,[]},
>                           transient,4294967295,worker,
>                           [rabbit_federation_sup]}},
>                   infinity]}}

**Shovel plugin:**

> c:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ
>   Server\rabbitmq_server-3.5.6\sbin>rabbitmq-plugi ns disable
>   rabbitmq_shovel The following plugins have been disabled:
>   rabbitmq_shovel
>
> Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@HOANGQUOCVI2118... failed.
>   Error: noproc

Please help me solve this case.

Comment: are you running rabbitmq as windows service?

Comment: ofcourse @Gabriele , like i said i use default option of RabbitMQ when install both computer.

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821094/cant-connect-to-rabbitmq-on-window-server-2012/32838164#32838164 , this is a cookie problem.

Comment: @Gabriele i know this guideline and try to reinstalled many time but error still happen , do you have any orther idea why ?

Comment: About the first problem, could you please verify if the node names are using uppercase or lowercase hostnames? Before RabbitMQ 3.6.0, node names' case could be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

About your second problem, it looks like the Erlang node is running, but the RabbitMQ application is stopped on this node.

After your attempts to cluster nodes, did you restart RabbitMQ?