# Memory limit set to 819MB of 4095MB total - RabbitMQ - How to set set_vm_memory_high_watermark

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

My rabbitMQ service is crashing as soon as I start it. The service was running fine for last two years but suddenly, it stopped working. I looked at the log and saw this:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 8-Oct-2015::11:40:56 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.0.2 on Erlang R16B

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Oct-2015::11:40:56 ===
Limiting to approx 8092 file handles (7280 sockets)

=WARNING REPORT==== 8-Oct-2015::11:40:56 ===
Only 2048MB of 4095MB memory usable due to limited address space.

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Oct-2015::11:40:56 ===
Memory limit set to 819MB of 4095MB total.

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Oct-2015::11:40:56 ===
Disk free limit set to 1000MB

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Oct-2015::11:40:56 ===
msg_store_transient: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Oct-2015::11:40:56 ===
msg_store_persistent: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Oct-2015::11:40:56 ===
started TCP Listener on [::]:5672

=ERROR REPORT==== 8-Oct-2015::11:40:56 ===
Error in process
```

**So I decided to run following commad:**

```
  rabbitmqctl set_vm_memory_high_watermark 0.5
```

**it gives following error:**

```
Setting memory threshold on rabbit@sn4324324 to 0.5 ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@sn4324324: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

nodes in question: [rabbit@sn4324324]

hosts, their running nodes and ports:
- sn4324324: [{rabbitmqctl601389,64542}]

current node details:
- node name: rabbitmqctl601389@sn4324324
- home dir: C:\Users\TestUser
- cookie hash: /GF4XhumN66/5SsNp0a8gQ==
```

**How can I set th value for set_vm_memory_high_watermark**

Comment: Does `rabbitmqctl status` work?

Comment: @Gabriele: it gives me followign error : `Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@MT1234234: nodedown`

Comment: The problem is not related to `set_vm_memory_high_watermark` but it is a `coojie` problem. Please read this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821094/cant-connect-to-rabbitmq-on-window-server-2012/32838164#32838164

Comment: @Gabriele: Thank you for reply. I checked and found that I have `.erlang.cookie` file is available in windows directory. The service was running fine for last two years and now suddenly, it has stopped working.

Comment: Having an erlang cookie doesn't mean you can connect to a particular node, since that cookie might not belong to the user trying to contact the other node. ie: you need the same user that runs the rabbitmq server to be sending those commands.